# Есть ли функция C для такой печати?

Tags: c, строки, функции, вывод

Я знаю только `printf` и использую только его, но я хочу попробовать функцию, которая может выводить что-то без использования % параметров.

Я хочу сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
printf("Привет, %s.\n", nazvaniye);
```

Но больше не использую % для этого. Что-то вроде:

```
foo("Привет, ");
foo(nazvaniye);
foo(".\n");
```

Есть ли такая функция?

Comment: Есть `puts`, но все данные придется самому переводить в строковый формат.

Comment: [man fputs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно - если в строке нет случайных `%` с чем-нибудь, что даст форматную строку, использовать непосредственно `printf`:

```
printf("Hello");
```

Если вывод должен завершаться переходом на новую строку - можно использовать `puts`, которая этот переход добавляет:

```
puts("Hello");
```

Наиболее честно отработает функция `fputs`, которой только надо указать, куда выводим:

```
fputs("Hello",stdout);
```

Ну и совершенно ничего не стоит написать такую функцию самостоятельно, типа

```
void foo(const char * s)
{
    for(;*s;fputc(*s++,stdout));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно выводить только строки, то напишите свою, используя массив строк. В конце нужно только добавлять нулевой указатель для того, чтобы функция смогла распознать конец массива.

```
// -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -std=c11 -Os
#include <stdio.h>

void prints ( char const * * s ) {
    char const * * j = s ;
    while ( * j ) {
        fputs ( * j , stdout ) ;
        ++ j ; } }

int main(){
    char const * s = "asdf";
    prints ( ( char const * [ ] ) {
      "12345" , s , "+-*/\n" , NULL } ) ;
}
```